# R regular expression: isolate a string between quotes

Tags: regex, r, quotes

I have a string `myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)`. I want to isolate what is in between quotes (`\"hop\"` in this example)

I have tried so far with no success:

```
gsub(pattern="(myFunction)(\\({1}))(.*)(\\\"{1}.*\\\"{1})(.*)(\\){1})",replacement="//4",x="myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)")
```

Any help by a regex guru would be welcome!

Comment: Do you need `\"hop\"` or `hop` as the answer as the description is in between quotes?

Comment: What do you mean by isolate? What would be your expected output?

Comment: for instance `\"hop\"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `regmatches` function also. Sub or gsub only works for a particular input , for general case you must do grabing instead of removing.

```
> x <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)"
> regmatches(x, gregexpr('"[^"]*"', x))[[1]]
[1] "\"hop\""
```

To get only the text inside quotes then pass the result of above function to a  gsub function which helps to remove the quotes.

```
> x <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)"
> gsub('"', '', regmatches(x, gregexpr('"([^"]*)"', x))[[1]])
[1] "hop"
> x <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=\"TRUE\")"
> gsub('"', '', regmatches(x, gregexpr('"([^"]*)"', x))[[1]])
[1] "hop"  "TRUE"
```

Answer (score 10):

Try

```
 sub('[^\"]+\"([^\"]+).*', '\\1', x)
 #[1] "hop"
```

Or

```
 sub('[^\"]+(\"[^\"]+.).*', '\\1', x)
 #[1] "\"hop\""
```

The `\"` is not needed as `"` would work too

```
 sub('[^"]*("[^"]*.).*', '\\1', x)
 #[1] "\"hop\""
```

If there are multiple matches, as @AvinashRaj mentioned in his post, `sub` may not be that useful.  An option using `stringi` would be

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_all_regex(x1, '"[^"]*"')[[1]]
 #[1] "\"hop\""  "\"hop2\""
```

#### data

```
 x <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)"
 x1 <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE arg3=\"hop2\", arg4=TRUE)"
```

Comment: many thanks, this works great. Could you explain the rationale for the first solution?

Comment: @RockScience The first solution matches all characters that are not `\"` i.e `[^\"]+`, followed by a `\"`,  and then use capture groups (within parentheses) to get the characters that not `\"`, use `\\1` to extract the capture group.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
str='myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)'

gsub('.*(\\".*\\").*','\\1',str)
#[1] "\"hop\""
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "myFunction(arg1=\"hop\",arg2=TRUE)"
unlist(strsplit(x,'"'))[2]
# [1] "hop"
```

Comment: with `paste0("\"",unlist(strsplit(x,'\"',perl=T))[2],"\"")` to get the desired result... (check the comments after the OP's question)